# Saving data to mongoDB in loop undefiend

Tags: javascript, mongodb, asynchronous

I have a function that read XML and map it to JSON then this JSON is saved in loop into MongoDB. Functions workd fine data is saved but... in line where i have 'Row Saved' i have this console log.... I think this undefined is because mongodb save() doesn;t have newData to save is waiting for it from loop. once it is it logs Row Saved. How to get rid off undefiend? Also can you please them me how to end this saving loop? becasue when it "stops" after 20-30 sec i starts again to save... so my code i not ended.

```
undefiend
undefiend
Row Saved
Row Saved
Row Saved
undefiend
undefiend
```

Code:

```
 function FileToFetch(dir) {
    fs.readdir(dir, async function(err, files) {
      const results = [];
      const files_path = files
        .map(function(fileName) {
          return {
            name: fileName,
            time: fs.statSync(dir + "/" + fileName).mtime.getTime()
          };
        })
        .sort(function(a, b) {
          return a.time - b.time;
        })
        .map(function(v) {
          return dir + "/" + v.name;
        });
      for (let index = 0; index < files_path.length; index++) {
        const element = files_path[index];
        results.push(element);
      }

      for (let index = 0; index < results.length; index++) {
        const element = results[index];

        let asd = await readFile(element, "utf8");
        parseString(asd, async (err, result) => {
          if (err) {
            throw err;
          } else {
            if (result.test !== undefined) {
              for (
                let index = 0;
                index < result.test.length;
                index++
              ) {
                const element = result.test[index];
                const newData = new Month({

                  name3: element.$.MetaDataVersionOID,

                });
                if (newData) {
                  newData
                    .save()
                    .then(() => console.log("Row Saved"))
                    .then(err => console.log(err));
                }
              }
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
  FileToFetch("./testing");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first of all you have to change

```
        newData
                .save()
                .then(() => console.log("Row Saved"))
                .then(err => console.log(err));
```

to get rid of the **undefined** since second then block will resolve undefined

```
        newData
                .save()
                .then(() => console.log("Row Saved"))
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

i don't really get what you mean about how to end save loop but i think you want some kind of sequential behavior, you can add **wait** keyword before this newData block

```
        await newData
                .save()
                .then(() => console.log("Row Saved"))
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: hey, i will give it try. what i want to do is  iterated over files in directory, read each file and then save it content to db. important i file there can be from 1 to 50 rows of data that i also iterate to save each one as separated object (Month). So i first get list of files from dir then read each one and for each one i read it content which has up to 50 rows and each row is saved to db.

Comment: thanks, maybe it not solved my problem only adding await i also switched all code to async await